Gradle depend on task within another module
I have module A depending on module B.
dependencies {
   implementation project(":module-B")
}

I have custom task 1 in module B that need to run before custom task 1 in module A?
How do I setup this dependency correct as the code above isn't enough.

It sounds like you are trying to implement an anti-pattern. Could you provide more context about what you are trying to do? With 14.3k reputation you should know https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

// module-A/build.gradle

customTaskOne {
    dependsOn ':module-B:customTaskOne'
}


Such a cross-project task dependency is not recommended due to its fragility and I write more about the correct approach in this answer, but this is useful for a quick solution.
